# How to rename /dev/sdax(partitions) in Linux

Tags: mount, fstab, partitioning, rename, uuid

I made a partition like `/part` on my machine with some important data...

But I can't stand the name of it...

I want a clear solution to resolve it and change the name of it to for example `/test`...

As you see this is my `/etc/fstab` information:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=a21a99c4-e5b4-4197-ac5e-80d0fab1f30c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=2e37d833-ca34-4fa7-a5d8-a4423a5af9bc /home           ext4    defaults          0       2
# /part was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=47e6e0b1-0e57-4184-a378-375b9ce315c5 /part           ext4    defaults          0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=485e9f78-4dce-4404-af4e-f43985525264 none            swap    sw                0       0
```

The point is: My information are important and I scare to manipulate it without being sure...
I want a safe solution...

How is it possible?

Thank you in advance

Comment: unclear what you are asking.Did you want to change `/dev/sdax` to `/part` like that?

Comment: no...I have `/part` dir in my machine but it relates to /dev/sdax..I want to rename `/part` to `/test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Unmount the partition:

  ```
  # umount /part
  ```
- Rename the directory after making sure it's not mounted:

  ```
  # mountpoint /part &>/dev/null || mv /part /best_name_ever
  ```
- Edit `/etc/fstab` to replace `/part` with `/best_name_ever`
- Remount the partition:

  ```
  mount /best_name_ever
  ```

The `#` is of course meant to represent your `root` prompt, not actual input to be typed in.

**To test the safety of this solution or any other one on dummy data**

The following instructions are (in part) stolen from [Virtual Filesystem: Building A Linux Filesystem From An Ordinary File](http://freecode.com/articles/virtual-filesystem-building-a-linux-filesystem-from-an-ordinary-file).

- Create an ordinary file with a size of 20 MB (for example):

  ```
  $ dd if=/dev/zero of=dummy_fs bs=1k count=20480 # 20480 = 20 * 1024
  ```
- Create an `ext4` filesystem on your file:

  ```
  $ /sbin/mkfs -t ext4 dummy_fs       
  mke2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
  dummy_fs is not a block special device.
  Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
  ... # Output of mkfs
  ```
- Mount the filesystem image, create some dummy data on it and test the solution:

  ```
  # mkdir /tmp/testmount
  # mount -o loop dummy_fs /tmp/testmount
  # touch /tmp/testmount/{blah,bleh} # Create dummy data
  # ls /tmp/testmount
  blah bleh lost+found
  # umount /tmp/testmount
  # mountpoint /tmp/sexy_name &>/dev/null || mv /tmp/testmount /tmp/sexy_name
  # mount -o loop dummy_fs /tmp/sexy_name
  # ls /tmp/sexy_name # to ensure your data is intact:
  blah bleh lost+found
  ```

Answer (score 2):

If you created the partition and set up /etc/fstab to mount it in /part, and want it now to be mounted in /test, then create the /test directory, and change /etc/fstab, then unmount and remount it.

Comment: How can I change it, My data is important and I scare

Comment: @MortezaLSC, the same way you changed it the first time; with your favorite text editor.

Answer (score 1):

In [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/), Unmount it, and then you change the 'Label', which affects the given name and mount point.
 So if I changed this partition label to 'Data', it would have the label/name 'Data', and the mountpoint would become `/media/wmobbs/Data`.

[image: example]

Labels work best without spaces, and any special characters.

---

If that does not work, change these lines in your `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /part was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=47e6e0b1-0e57-4184-a378-375b9ce315c5 /part           ext4    defaults          0       2
```

to:

```
# /part was on /dev/sda7 during installation - mountpoint changed to /test
UUID=47e6e0b1-0e57-4184-a378-375b9ce315c5 /test           ext4    defaults          0       2
```

You can edit the file by running `sudo nano /etc/fstab`, then applying the above changes, and saving with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. 
You then need to run `sudo mkdir /test` to create the needed folder - **note that the folder needs to be empty**. 
You have to reboot for any changes to take effect

Comment: I unmounted it with gparted, then clicked on `label` and set test...then accepted it..but nothing changed:(

Comment: Try @psusi 's answer - `/etc/fstab` just changes the mount points etc, and should not harm your data - I'll expand on that in an edit.

Comment: Thank you...I next solution shouldn't I use mount and umount commands?

Comment: Yes, you can just run `sudo umount /part` and then `sudo mount test` rather than rebooting.  And then `sudo rmdir /part` when you're happy. :)

Comment: @MLSC You need to apply your changes in GParted, it's the right-most button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the /dev/sda partition on the mount point /test. For an example, see http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/01/mount-umount-examples/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please don't add 'thanks' as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Ask Ubuntu way of saying thank you.